# Why can't I display data from Firebase Realtime Database into a UITableView?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve my data from the Firebase Realtime Database, however, the data is not appearing in my `UITableView`. I am retrieving the data and trying to append it to an array that is of type of a data model I have created called `Party`. I am not sure how to setup up my code so I can successfully get the data from Firebase to my `UITableView` and I am also not sure where the problem lies.

I have tried reording my code and using different methods to retrieve data from Firebase but nothing worked. I created an array called parties which store information of type `Party`.

The following is my code for the override function of the `UITableViewController`. This is where most of the code for my Firebase Database rests. This is a table view with custom cells.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Set the Firebase reference.
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        // Retrieve the parties and listen for changes.
        ref?.child("parties").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Take the value from the snapshot and add it to the parties array.
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let titleText = value?["titleText"] as? String ?? "Title"
            let dateText = value?["dateText"] as? String ?? "Date"
            let timeText = value?["timeText"] as? String ?? "Time"

            self.parties.append(Party(title: titleText, date: dateText, time: timeText))
        })

        tableView.reloadData()

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourPartiesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? YourPartiesTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of YourPartiesTableViewController")
        }

        let party = parties[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell
        cell.titleLabel.text = party.titleText
        cell.dateAndTimeLabel.text = "\(party.dateText) at \(party.timeText)"
        cell.inviationsLabel.text = "0 people"
        cell.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        return cell
    }
```

I expected it to append the data from Firebase to the parties array. Then, I wanted that data to show on the table view. Why is that not happening? Where am I wrong in my code?

Comment: call tableView.reloadData() inside the asyncronous call.

Comment: please don't do database calls within cellForRow at..Do a database call before you instantiate the controller, and pass the data to the controller, and then do a tableview.reloadData(). 
While typing that, maybe check out some tutorials which should help you write code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't load any data inside `cellForRowAt` as it's called for every instance inside the dataSource array and remove `reloadData` also as not cause recursive calls

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return parties.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourPartiesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? YourPartiesTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of YourPartiesTableViewController")
        }

        let party = parties[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell
        cell.titleLabel.text = party.titleText
        cell.dateAndTimeLabel.text = "\(party.dateText) at \(party.timeText)"
        cell.inviationsLabel.text = "0 people"
        cell.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        return cell
    }
func loadData() {

    // Set the Firebase reference.
    ref = Database.database().reference() 
    // Retrieve the parties and listen for changes.
    ref?.child("parties").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Take the value from the snapshot and add it to the parties array.
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let titleText = value?["titleText"] as? String ?? "Title"
        let dateText = value?["dateText"] as? String ?? "Date"
        let timeText = value?["timeText"] as? String ?? "Time" 
        self.parties.append(Party(title: titleText, date: dateText, time: timeText)) 
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }) 

 }
```

Call `loadData` from `viewDidLoad`